# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.gms.pay.factoryreset.PayFactoryResetReceiver: fnqb: lateinit property …

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin

I have a React Native application, and when i build the .aab and uploaded to Google Play Console, after the review(testing), I got the following Error and I can't find what cause this. React Native version: **0.68.2**

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.gms.pay.factoryreset.PayFactoryResetReceiver: fnqb: lateinit property executor has not been initialized
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4458)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleReceiver
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2256)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:205)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:294)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8177)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:552)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by fnqb: lateinit property executor has not been initialized
  at com.google.android.gms.pay.factoryreset.PayFactoryResetChimeraReceiver.a (:com.google.android.gms@235014038@23.50.14 (190400-592568214):8)
  at com.google.android.gms.pay.factoryreset.PayFactoryResetChimeraReceiver.onReceive (:com.google.android.gms@235014038@23.50.14 (190400-592568214):921)
  at ahbu.a (:com.google.android.gms@235014038@23.50.14 (190400-592568214):34)
  at ocl.onReceive (:com.google.android.gms@235014038@23.50.14 (190400-592568214):32)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4449)
```

I will appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: Same issue with a native application, did you find something to fix it ?